# SCP a file that match a particular pattern and extension

Tags: linux, unix, scp

I am trying to SCP a file from a remote host onto local host.

The file on the remote host would be, KMST_DataFile_[MMDDYY]T[HHMM].kms

I have come up with 2 SCP commands, but I was wondering if there's a way to combine these, to only SCP file that match both the file name pattern above and the extension .kms

scp -v user@remotehost:/location/KMST_DataFile_*

scp -v user@remotehost:/location/{*.kms}

Comment: You need to understand that unquoted meta characters like `*` are expanded by your local shell (i.e. on your local machine).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will do your job:

```
scp -v user@remotehost:/location/KMST_DataFile_*.kms
```

As @manu mentioned in the comment, on Ubuntu or Mac, you may need to escape the asterisk:

```
scp -v user@remotehost:/location/KMST_DataFile_\*.kms
```

Comment: Doesn't really help, or am I wrong? At least from MacOS to Ubuntu, the asterix is not expanded.

Comment: You have to escape the asterisk character, so it'll be more like this: 
scp -v user@remotehost:/location/KMST_DataFile_\*.kms

Comment: On MacOS, you need to escape `*` with a back slash like so `scp -v user@remotehost:/location/KMST_DataFile_\*.kms` for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `\*` instead of using `*`

`scp -v user@remotehost:/location/KMST_DataFile_\*`

Answer (score 3):

**The main thing here is to use recursive mode `-r` even if you copy files and not directories. It works.**

If you want to copy files that start with "val" and contain also the string "v2" then use:

```
scp -r makis@server.gr:/media/Data/results/val*v2* /Users/makis/Desktop/
```

Here, `vecs*v2*` will expand and get only files that start with `val` and also contain `v2` string.

---

Similarly, if the files end with `.png` for example use:

```
scp -r makis@server.gr:/media/Data/results/val*.png /Users/makis/Desktop/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh user@host 'tar cf - /location/KMST_DataFile_* /location/{*.kms}' | tar tvpf -
```

Note that these `tar`options only give you a table of contents.  You'll want to check before you extract, and almost certainly remove the absolute path.

Comment: Also note that his doesn't answer the question in a clever globbing manner, that is one file glob which catches all of the files, but is rather a more generalized solution for when a file glob won't do.